# How to call function using EclipseLink

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, sys-refcursor

How to call an Oracle function which returns sys_refcursor using EclipseLink?

There is a documentation which states about calling a function, but not sure how to call a function which returns sys_refcursor.

http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_namedstoredfunctionquery.htm

I have tried as follows

```
@NamedStoredFunctionQuery(name = "findEmployees", 
                          functionName = "getEmps", 
                          parameters = 
                          { @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter = "user", 
                                                      name = "username", 
                                                      direction = Direction.IN, 
                                                      type = String.class)
            } , 
    returnParameter = @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter = "c_cursor")
)
```

Oracle Function

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION getEmps (username varchar2)
      RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
   AS
   c_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
   BEGIN
   OPEN c_cursor FOR 
   SELECT * FROM employees where emp_no=username;
   RETURN c_cursor;
```

However when I execute, I am getting the following errors

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
>       PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
>       ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> Error Code: 6550
>       Call: BEGIN ? := getEmps(username=>?); END;
>           bind => [=> c_cursor, S7845]
>       Query: DataReadQuery(name="findEmps" )
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: can post your plsql storedFunction  ?

Comment: may be You tried to execute an invalid block of PLSQL function, but a compilation error occurred.

Comment: @CHHIBIAMOR I have included my PLSQL function in my question and function is compiled and I have been executing it from other programs successfully. When I attempted to call using EclipseLink, then I have not been successful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must specify the `Direction` of the functions parmeter

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION getEmps (username IN varchar2)
      RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
   AS
   c_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
   BEGIN
   OPEN c_cursor FOR 
   SELECT * FROM employees where emp_no=username;
   RETURN c_cursor;
```

Try it, please !

Comment: Will try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Save the function on database and then execute it with FUNCTION call.

For example, i have an Oracle function called 'SUMACAMPO' that sums two columns of the DB:

[image]

And my query:

```
select Function('SUMACAMPO') from Table t
```

Java Code:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select Function('SUMACAMPO') from Table t");
List<Object[]> resultado= q.getResultList();
LOG.info("Resultado consulta: {}",resultado);
```

so, the output of execute the query in LOG is:

```
Resultado consulta: [4413700]
```