# Calling oracle function returning array of numbers in eclipseLink

Tags: java, sql, oracle, function, eclipselink

I have an oracle function which returns an array of integers for which a type has been written at database. Code is as follows :

```
create or replace type my_ids is table of number;
```

By looking at the examples present online I am trying to call that function but it is always saying

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation
```

Here is code snippet which I tried:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "My_Table")
@NamedStoredFunctionQuery(name = "get_ids", functionName = "my_function", 
parameters = 
{
@StoredProcedureParameter(name = "batch_size", queryParameter = "batch_size", type = Long.class)
},
returnParameter = @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT , name= "my_ids" , queryParameter = "my_ids" , jdbcType = OracleTypes.ARRAY))
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

//Fields
// 

}
```

By analyzing the error I am getting, I know there is some problem with defining returnParameter but I am not sure what exactly I am missing. Please help me with the code. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call function using EclipseLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961486/how-to-call-function-using-eclipselink)

Comment: 2 things to consider before saying it duplicate. I saw that question already. It uses ref_cursor which I don't. It does not have an answer also.

Comment: Its not an array but a table, a PL/SQL construct that isn't supported directly through JDBC which JPA uses underneath. see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/oracledb002.htm#CHDDCIEC